# How to calculate past or future date based on input date value in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

I am trying to calculate the past date based on the input date value provided by a user to a bash script.

For instance if user provides input value as `20240224` (`YYYYMMDD` format) I want to calculate the date the which is 2 days ago. So, in this case the calculated date should be `20240222`.

As per my understanding Linux/bash has below option to calculate it from the current date as below.

```
date -d "2 days ago" +%Y%m%d
```

How can I calculate, based on the user input value?
Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Type a date, format: [YYYYMMDD] >>> ' d
if [[ $d =~ ^[0-9]{8}$ ]]; then
    date -d "$d 2 days ago" '+%Y%m%d'
else
    echo >&2 "Wrong input $d"
    exit 1
fi
```

Yields:

```
20240222
```